# How you Change MUI icon border thickness

Tags: material-ui, icons

How you Change MUI icon border thickness

- suppose this icon is having thickness how to make setting icon border lighter

[image]

Comment: There isn't such thing as "thickness" in svg like `font-weight` in css, it's all vector paths. The only way to make it thinner is to edit the pathing, preferably with a vector graphics tool like Adobe Illustrator.

Answer (score 7):

There is a trick with css (stroke must have the same color as your background)

```
<YourMuiIcon sx={{ stroke: "#ffffff", strokeWidth: 1 }} />
```